Type of convergence for empirical distribution
The master equation of a stochastic process is an equation that describes the evolution of the probability of that stochastic process. In physics, the master equation is also called the hydrodynamic limit (at least, I think this is true).
My interpretation of the master equation is that if you have $n$ particles that all follow the same stochastic process, then the empirical distribution $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$ converges to the solution of the master equation.
Can we say that the stochastic process converges in some sense to the solution of the master equation? There isn't really a sequence of stochastic processes, which is where we usually use notions of convergence. But there is a convergence happening, and that's of the empirical distribution to the solution of the master equation.

The master equation describes the time evolution of the probability distribution $ p(t, x) $ for a stochastic process. In the context of systems with $n$ particles, where each particle follows the same stochastic process, it is indeed correct that the empirical distribution
$$
\mu_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i(t)}
$$
converges to $p(t, x)$ as $ n \to \infty $.
This convergence happens in the sense that the empirical measure $\mu_n(t) $, which is random for finite $n$, converges weakly to the deterministic $ p(t, x) $. This weak convergence means that for any test function $ \varphi $,
$$
   \int \varphi(x) \, d\mu_n(t)(x) \to \int \varphi(x) \, p(t, x) \, dx
$$
almost surely.
So there isn’t really a sequence of stochastic processes directly converging to $ p(t, x) $, but we can still say there is a form of convergence happening, like before.

Thank you for the answer. Can you explain why the weak convergence holds for the master equation to the solution of the ODE?
